# Haskell: foldl Function applied as infix Function?

Tags: haskell, fold, infix-operator, foldleft

Is the function I give to `foldl` applied in an infix way?

Example

```
foldl (-) 0 [1,2,3]

= 0-1-2-3 
= -6
```

so more generally:

```
foldl f x [a,b,c]
```

is applied as:

```
(((x `f` a) `f`  b) `f` c)
```

I know it's recursive, but can I think about it that way?

Comment: Infix is just syntax.  You are correct about the nesting of the calls, but being infix or prefix doesn't matter.  (Also, note that the syntax to use a prefix function infix uses backticks, not single quotes.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference between infix function application and prefix function application is syntax, so your question does not make very much sense. Outside of referring to the syntax of a particular expression, applying a function “in an infix way” doesn’t mean anything.

In Haskell, when you write `x + y`, it is precisely equivalent to writing `(+) x y`. Likewise, `` x `op` y `` is precisely equivalent to writing `op x y`. Put another way, application of an infix operator is still just plain old function application where the function is applied to two arguments.

If it helps you to visualize `foldl` via an expression like `` ((a `f` b) `f` c) `f` d `` instead of one like `f (f (f a b) c) d`, that’s certainly within your right, since the two expressions are equivalent. Indeed, the documentation for `foldl` uses infix notation to help explain the function’s behavior, since it is a useful representation that helps get the point across. But be careful not to confuse *notation* (aka syntax) with *denotation* (aka meaning). Many programs can be notationally distinct but denotationally equivalent.